# Having trouble with MySQL wildcard characters

Tags: mysql, macos, wildcard

Im following the instructions on w3schools but something appears to not be working. I keep getting the result "empty set" even though it seems like multiple names should be returned since there is names that start with a,l and c.

BTW I am using MySQL via the terminal on a mac. Thank you.

[here is a picture of the table I'm using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e384B.png)

Here is my syntax -

mysql> select * from Student where Name like '[alc]%';

Answer (score 0):

With your select you search for a patter that  exactly matches '[alc]'
followed by anything denoted by %.

Try regexp like this.

```
 select * from Student where Name regexp '^(a|l|c)';
```

This will give you names that start with the given letters, not case sensitiv

Comment: Do you know any resources to learn about using wildcard characters?

Comment: For learning about regular expressions I use these

https://regex101.com/
https://www.phpliveregex.com/